# (ftp://user:pass@hostname/path) stopped working after I implemented openssl

Tags: php, ftp, php-openssl

I own an online FTP using PHP and since `mcrypt` has been deprecated I wanted to switch to `openssl` to continue encrypting and storing user credentials as a cookie (deletes when the browser session ends). I know for a fact that the encryption process is working correctly as I have full functionality of everything, but the ftp:// path. I have also echoed out the values inside the cookie after it has been encrypted and decrypted and they were exactly what they were before I encrypted them.

This is just one example of something that doesn't work now, but worked before:

```
$file=fopen("ftp://$u:$p@$h".$_GET['dir'],"r") or die("Couldn't open file");
```

> **Warning:** fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in hidden on line hidden

I don't understand why this is happening and I would be very applicable to give any code that might be needed in determining why this is occurring. However, I can't post code that may compromise the security of my site. Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe try using `sftp` instead of `ftp`.

Comment: I just tried that I receive the same error ):

Comment: I think @Nicolas means `ftps`. `sftp` is file transfer over SSH where `ftps` is `ftp` with `ssl`. Not sure it will fix the issue, but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: Do you mean to use ```(ftps://user:pass@hostname/path)```? If so, the same error is outputted.

Comment: @JNevill You're right, sorry about that.

Comment: @JNevill Why would I need to switch the whole connection type to SSL? The only thing that I changed that is causing this error is the encryption/decryption method. I just don't understand why this is happening in the first place. If the values of the variables are the exact same as before then why would any such errors occur.

Comment: @GriffinGarman You will need to change ftp_connect to ftp_ssl_connect to use ftps

Comment: @4424dev okay, but why?

Comment: @GriffinGarman your server may be rejecting insecure connections (as ftp is insecure) and ftp_ssl_connect encrypts the connecion so it is secure

Comment: @4424dev then why was it working before?

Comment: Okay I tried ```ftp_ssl_connect``` with ftps:// and the same exact error is outputted. This makes no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that there are extra characters in the decryption. You can't see these characters so you don't know that they are there. Use the following:

```
strval(str_replace("\0", "","ftp://$u:$p@$h".$_GET['dir']))
```